# Creating my own simple CMS for asp.net-mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I want to create a simple CMS for my asp.net-mvc site. Will I save my whole page to a database? What if my page contain links like:

```
Url.Content("~/somepage")
```

When the admin will edit the page he will get the plain link not the `Url.Content`. How I can handle this in CMS?

Is there any CMS available based on subsonic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? Check out the [Orchard Project](http://www.orchardproject.net/), also [on GitHub](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard) - which is an open-source ASP.NET MVC CMS just like the one you're thinking about creating.

Maybe you can just use Orchard instead - or download its source code and learn from it?

Comment: +1, great idea to learn from an existing CMS especially one for which you have the source code.